# Customize Windows CMD for MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I am working on building a new build box which I would like to contain only bare bones essentials for .NET builds. I have installed the .NET 4.0 framework and now I would like to set up a command prompt that recognizes the `msbuild` command.

I've tried copying over the Visual Studio Command Prompt from my machine but it is missing a lot of prereqs to initialize properly and I feel like it includes way to much stuff anyway as all I need is the `msbuild` command.

So, is there a way to make the windows cmd to recognize the `msbuild` command through possibly a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the framework tools to your Path environment variable.
Default: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version number]

It should also run just fine if you use the full path in the command line.

Comment: I don't want to do that I want to be able to say `msbuild ...` as it is possible for the framework to exist in different locations on different machines and I don't want a custom build process for the build box

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate to ask, but since my answer had your solution in it would you accept it as the answer?

Comment: if you update your solution to specify that it needs to be added to the path environment variable not the path of the cmd when inputting the command I will accept as an answer, as of now I feel as if its incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I added the location of the msbuild.exe to my Path system variable and now it works just fine.